# using alarm to get parent process to wait on child process for a number of seconds

Tags: c, process, signals, fork, alarm

I need to create a c file that takes in two arguments `WAIT, and TIME`.

The code should ﬁrst fork() a child process which does work for W seconds and then exits. The parent process should wait on the child, but for T seconds maximum.

After T seconds of waiting, the parent process should stop waiting and print the the message "Timed out after T seconds.", and exit.

On the other hand, if the child terminates before the timeout, the parent should print the message "Child done." and exit.

I want to try and use the `alarm()` function to do this but I am stuck on how exactly.

```
#include <stdio.h>


int int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int W = atoi(argv[1]); 
    int T = atoi(argv[2]);
    pid_t pid = fork(); 
    if (pid ==0){
        sleep(W); 

    }
    else{
        alarm(T); 
            //REST OF CODE HERE

    }

    return 0;
}
```

I do not have much because I am trying to wrap my head around how to make the parent wait on the child for the given number of seconds.

Your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is `SIGCHLD` ...this is a signal sent to the parent when a child changes status. There is a system call expressly designed to wait for this signal, appropriately called `wait`. There are 4 status changes that can trigger the signal, and the `wait` manpage documents how to check for them:

1. The child terminates normally
2. The child was terminated by a signal
3. The child was stopped by a signal
4. The child was continued by a signal

`wait` will block the parent until it receives a signal--either `SIGCHLD` or another unignored signal. This means your strategy of using `alarm` should work perfectly (however, you should note that the default action for `SIGALRM` is to terminate the program, so if that's not what you want, you'll need to change it):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int W;
    int T;
    int status;
    pid_t pid;
    if(argc != 3) return 1;
    W = atoi(argv[1]);
    T = atoi(argv[2]);
    pid = fork();
    if(pid == 0)
    {
        sleep(W);
    }
    else
    {
        alarm(T);
        if(wait() == -1)
        {
            /*
            This will not actually run unless you override
            the default action for SIGALRM
            */
        }
        else
        {
             /*Child changed state*/
             /*Check how with WIF... macros*/
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

You have one other option that may be a bit more work, but you might want to explore it. There is another system call named `sigtimedwait` which can wait for a set of signals (including `SIGCHLD`) with a timeout.